# iOS app - Fix Apple not allowing you link website for payment?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, in-app-purchase

I have an app which require user (loggin required) to pay before they can use (not Apple InApp Purchase), kind of like DropBox.

Of course there will be user don't sign up for my plan first and downloaded the app, what step should I do in my app in order to tell them to pay from my website?

Seems I cannot link to my website, so how can I tell them to pay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as you said you cannot make direct link from within the app to the payment other than IAP, maybe you should make website for signup/payment. and the only thing you can do in the app is to tell user that the user need to have the account of the website. direct link seens to not allowed